# C# - How to delete selected rows from a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, datagrid, sql-delete

I am trying to delete the row which the user selects in a DataGridView in a C# WinForms app (connected to a local DB that has records already).

I have implemented the code below, and there are no errors, but the delete is never picked up (even though messagebox shows that a record has been 'deleted', which is not true, as the record remains in the DataGrid)

Please also note that the delete function is within a Search function - please see below code.

```
public void DisplayData()
    {
        string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename= C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Library System Project.mdf ;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

        string Query = "select * from Customers";

        SqlConnection DBCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand DBCommand = new SqlCommand(Query, DBCon);
        SqlDataReader DBReader;

        try
        {
            DBCon.Open();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(DBCommand);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dgv_CustomerDetails.DataSource = dt;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            // *** If you're going to be opening a connection be sure to close it ***
            // *** Finally blocks work well for this ***
            DBCon.Close();
        }
    }


    private void SearchCustomerRecordForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayData();
    }


    private void btnDeleteCustomerRecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename= C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Library System Project.mdf ;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";

        int rowIndex = dgv_CustomerDetails.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

        string Query = "delete from Customers where CustomerName = '"+ dgv_CustomerDetails.CurrentCell(rowIndex) +"'";

        SqlConnection DBCon = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand DBCommand = new SqlCommand(Query, DBCon);
        SqlDataReader DBReader;

        try
        {
            DBCon.Open();
            DBReader = DBCommand.ExecuteReader();
            MessageBox.Show("Customer record removed from the system.", "Library System", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            // *** If you're going to be opening a connection be sure to close it ***
            // *** Finally blocks work well for this ***
            DBCon.Close();
            DisplayData();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that Query is created well? It seems that there is missing Cell Value property in that row:

```
string Query = "delete from Customers where CustomerName = '"+ dgv_CustomerDetails.CurrentCell(rowIndex).value +"'";
```

try to look at the value of Query variable since it is builded up.

Comment: Hi Jan, I have changed the query to 'where CustomerID' instead of CustomerName, but I get the error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value to data type int

Comment: I also tried to query above, and its giving me an error with CurrentCell (Non invocable member 'DataGridView.CurrentCell' cannot be used like a method.)

Comment: When I am using it, Im not getting values directly from the cells but from the datalayer this way: (sorry Im the VB.NET person)
 Dim dat As DataRowView = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).DataBoundItem
ID = dat.Item("CustomerID")

Comment: And since you referencing number, it must not be enclosed in apostrophes.